# Why Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main?

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

Well as I researched it seems to be a common error, but through the information I collected, it is mainly caused by the misbehaviour of main method, while in here I inspected nothing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NBody {

    public static void main(double T, double dt, String filename) {

        In f = new In(filename);
        int N = f.readInt();
        double R = f.readDouble();

        Planet planets[] = new Planet[N]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            planets[i] = getPlanet(f);
        }

        StdDraw.setScale(-R, R);

        for (Planet star:planets) {
            star.draw();
        }
    /*
        for (Planet star:planets) {
            star.update(dt);
            StdDraw.picture(star.x, star.y, star.imgName);
        }
    */

    }

    public static Planet getPlanet(In file) {
        double x = file.readDouble();
        double y = file.readDouble();
        double xVelocity = file.readDouble();
        double yVelocity = file.readDouble();
        double mass = file.readDouble();
        String imgName = file.readString();
        Planet p = new Planet(x, y, xVelocity, yVelocity, mass, imgName);
        return p;
    }

}
```

So how can I solve this problem? I didn't transfer any arguments to it and the java NBody just fails (I compiled successfully, I could assure that).

Comment: Your main method arguments are wrong. It's `main(String[] args)` or `main(String... args)` and nothing else. Successful compilation means nothing.

Comment: Because main can only get an array of String arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `main` method has the wrong signature. To be an entry point for a Java application, it must have a single parameter of type `String[]` (and a `void` return type, and it must be public and static):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

The parameter name is unimportant.

You'll need to parse the command line arguments into appropriate types, e.g.

```
// TODO: Validation, e.g. that there are 3 command line arguments
// TODO: Use meaningful and conventional variable names
double T = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
double dt = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
String filename = args[2];
```

Comment: Thank you. So how can I pass the listed arguments above to the main method?

Comment: You forgot to mention it should be `static` as well.

Comment: @tonyabracadabra: See my edited answer - basically, you need to parse the values that come from the command line.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I see what you mean. Why can't I drop the Double.parseDouble things?

Comment: @tonyabracadabra it depends what you want to do. If you want doubles, you need to do that as all the command line arguments come in as strings. You need to parse them to get Double objects.

Comment: @tonyabracadabra: Because the command line provides arguments as strings, not doubles. It's up to you to interpret that array of strings however you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
double T = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
double dt = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
String filename = args[2];
}
```

if your are using command prompt

javac NBody.java

java NBody {1stparam} {1stparam} {1stparam}

```
javac NBody.java 
java NBody 12.2 12.3 filamename
```

Space is the delimiter here

```
12.2 will be placed to args[0] 
12.3 will be placed to args[1] and 
filename will be placed to args[2].
```

since it is String you will be doing

```
  double value = Double.parseDouble(string);
```